# Matlab crashes with S-function after mdlOutputs

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, mex

I'm doing my "main" S-function based on the Matlab template with `mdlStart` `mdlOutputs`, etc, which communicates with some Ansi C files that I had, and this S-Function is used in Simulink. I compiled the files correctly with **mex** and in order to debug I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I can set and use breakpoints so everything is working fine.

The problem is, after finishing 'mdlOutputs' function, where all the contents are correctly printed into Matlab the debugging goes into a breakpoint and it goes into 'simulink.c'. After that, the Debug is broken saying that "libmex.pdb" cannot be found.

If I run the Simulink model without Visual Studio in the loop, Matlab just crashes and stops working.

So, any idea on how to check properly where it is giving me an error? Also, do you have any clue on why the process crashes after leaving `mdlOutputs` and before entering `mdlTerminate`? What happens in-between these two functions?

I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit and Matlab 2012b (I'm going to try and run it in the 2015b).

Answer (score 1):

I think that I finally found out the solution (even though I quite don't understand it yet).

In the `mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)` I substituted `ssSetOptions(S, 0);` by `ssSetOptions(S, SS_OPTION_EXCEPTION_FREE_CODE);` like it is suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/error-handling.html).

Comment: That option guarantees that your s-function is not throwing exceptions that cause long jumps in code. It is possible this option is masking some other problem that is causing the crash. Make sure you are not overwriting any memory in mdlOutputs.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. the thing is, how do I make sure no overwrites of memory are happening? Within Matlab + Visual Studio it is pretty difficult